# Generator of a σ-algebra under composition with a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ be a measurable space and $A \in \sigma(f_k : 
k \in \mathbb N)$ for some measurable functions $f_k:\Omega \rightarrow E $ into another measurable space $(E, \mathcal E)$.

Now consider $g:\Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ measurable.

Do we have $g^{-1}(A) \in \sigma(f_k\circ g: k \in \mathbb N)$?

**My attempt:** I suspect that the statement holds, since we can verify the statement directly for the sets of the form $f_k^{-1}(B)$ such that $B\in \mathcal E$, the sets which generate $\sigma(f_k : 
k \in \mathbb N)$. So the question arises whether it is enough to prove the result only for the generator?

Help appreciated.

Comment: What does $\sigma(f_k : 
k \in \mathbb N)$ mean?

Comment: $\sigma(f) = \sigma (f^{-1}(B) : B \in \mathcal E)$, sigma algebra generated by preimages of $f$, the smallest sigma algebra wrt which $f$ is measurable. Same construction for collection $\sigma (f_k: k \in \mathbb N)$

Comment: And I assume "$g:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F$" means $g:\Omega \to \Omega$ is measurable from $\mathcal F$ to $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Okay I confused domains for both functions, let me fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy to verify that $\{A\in \sigma \{f_1,f_2,\cdots\}:g^{-1}(A) \in \sigma \{f_1\circ g,f_2\circ g,\cdots\}\}$ is  a sigma algebra. Since it contains the generating sets it conatins the entire sigma algebra $\sigma \{f_1,f_2,\cdots\}$ and this is what we want to porve.

Comment: Nice argument, thanks